# Heroku linked to dropbox, cannot delete files

Tags: file, heroku, filesystems, dropbox

I have a Heroku app which is connected to Dropbox for deployment.
At some point during the project, I'd like to delete a few files which were deployed earlier but I am not able to do that.
I have tried the following two methods:

1. Disconnecting Dropbox from Heroku, reconnecting Dropbox to Heroku, completely cleaning the Dropbox folder and the deploying. All the old files, although not present in the Dropbox folder, are there in Heroku
2. Accessing the application via the Heroku command line interface, removing files manually; when I logout and then login again, the files are always there.

I think that point n. 2 is due to the heroku filesystem, and that's ok. But why point n. 1 is not working? How could one delete a single file in Heroku (e.g. a text file previously loaded via Dropbox)?

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there a good reason to develop from a Dropbox folder? Why are you doing this? Are you using any versioning system like Git?

Comment: I have coded a very basic telegram bot, which required a few deployments and therefore I did use Dropbox not needing to manage too many versions.

Comment: I see. Have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku works](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works) with the concept of a deploy:

> The source code for your application, together with the fetched dependencies and output of the build phase such as generated assets or compiled code, as well as the language and framework, are assembled into a slug.

It is impossible for you to access a specific file within the deploy.

You can change the application on your development environment, doing whatever you want, and the rebuild the slug on Heroku.

The 'doing whatever you want' might as well be removing a file, as long as the build passes.